# how to skip recv() function when no data is sent

Tags: c, sockets, server, parent-child, recv

I have a server-client program written in C. My problem is that I have a while loop in which I receive and send data. it happens a lot when i need my server to do other things but it just stops at recv() function and waits for data from client. How can I overcome it? I've tried this:

```
 int waitForAnswer =1;
 if((childpid = fork()) == 0){
     close(socketfd);
     close(fd[0]);

        while(1){
            if(waitForAnswer) {
                receive(newSocket, buff) == 0;
                parseRecvMess(buff);
             }
             waitForAnswer  =0;
```

but it doesn't work. For some reason the program finishes with an exit code 1, at accepting socket with a "No Socket" error.
Here is my program ;

```
nt main(){
    int size = 256;
    char buff[size];
    char sbuff[size];
    int n;
    int reader;
    int socketfd, ret;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    int newSocket = -2;
    struct sockaddr_in newAddr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    pid_t childpid;
    pocet_hracu = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));
    initializeLobby();
    memset(buff, 0, size);
    memset(sbuff, 0, size);

    socketfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);


    if(socketfd < 0){
        printf("\n error in socket creation");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("\n Server socket is created\n");


    memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    ret = bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

    if(ret < 0){
        printf("Error in binding\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("[*]Bind to port %d\n", PORT);

    if(listen(socketfd, 10) == 0){
        printf("Listening...\n");
    }else{
        printf("Error in binding\n");
    }

    // pipe pro komunikaci
    int readpipe;
    int writepipe;
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    for (;;) {
            newSocket = accept(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &newAddr, &addr_size);
            if (newSocket < 0) {
                printf("No socket\n");
                exit(1);
            }
//            struct timeval tv;
//            tv.tv_sec = 1;
//            tv.tv_usec = 0;
//            setsockopt(socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof(tv));
            // read the message from client and copy it in buffer
            receive(newSocket, buff);
            parseRecvMess(buff);
            printf("\n%s sent: %s", user, command);

            if (strncmp(" new", command, 4) == 0) {
                player newPlayer;
                newPlayer.name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10); // *login must contain up to 10 characters
                strcpy(newPlayer.name, user);
                newPlayer.gameScore = 0;
                newPlayer.roundScore = 0;
                newPlayer.socket = newSocket;
                // TODO vztvorit pipe pro kounikaci
                // newPlayer.readpipe
                // newPlayer.writepipe
                addToPlayersArray(&newPlayer); //TODO player index is not increasing
                addToLobby(&newPlayer);
                printf("Server : %s uspesne prihlasen.\n", newPlayer.name);
            }


            bzero(buff, size);
            printf("To client : OK\n");
            strcpy(sbuff, "OK\n" );
            sendMess(newSocket, sbuff, sizeof(sbuff));

            int waitForAnswer =1;
        if((childpid = fork()) == 0){
            close(socketfd);
            close(fd[0]);

            while(1){
                printf("MAIN->while(1)\n");
                // poslouchame zpravy
                //if(waitForAnswer) {
                receive(newSocket, buff) == 0;
                parseRecvMess(buff);
                //}
                waitForAnswer  =0;




                if(strcmp(buff,":exit") == 0){
                    printf("Disconnected from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
                    break;
                } else{
                    // send buff to parent
                    int i = findPlayerIndex();
                    memset(sbuff, '\0', size)  ;
                    str str;
                    strcat(sbuff, "//:");
                    sprintf(str, "%d", i);
                    strcat(sbuff, str);
                    strcat(sbuff, ":");
                    strcat(sbuff, command);
                    strcat(sbuff, "\n");
                    write(fd[1], sbuff , strlen(sbuff)+1);
                    bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));



                    if (strncmp("roll", command, 4) == 0) {
                        //TODO

                        hod();
                    }
                    if (strncmp("none", command, 4) == 0) {
                        //TODO
                    }

                    strcpy(sbuff, "OK\n" );
                    write(newSocket, sbuff, strlen(sbuff));
                    bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
                    bzero(sbuff, sizeof(sbuff));
                }
            }
        } 
            close(fd[1]);
            int nbytes = read(fd[0], buff, sizeof(buff));
            printf("PARENT: buffer : %s\n",buff);

            parseRecvMess(buff);

            char *index1= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
            strcpy(index1, user);
            int index = atoi(index1);
            char *command1= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
            strcpy(command1, command);
            //printf("PARENT - index:%d, command:%s\n", index, command );
            printf("PARENT - index:%d, jmeno:%s, command:%s\n", index, players_array[index].name, command1 );
            bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));


        if (strncmp("room", command1, 4) == 0) {
                        // vlozit do mistnosti
                        printf("command = room\n");
                        command = strtok(command1," ");
                        command = strtok(NULL," "); // volba
                        printf("command(volba): + %s \n", command);
                        //int i = findPlayerIndex(); // find player in array based on user name
                        printf("player index: = %d \n", index);
                        //printPlayer(&players_array[i]);
                        volbaHry(&players_array[index], command, lobby);
                        //players_array[i].mist->pocet_hracu++;
                        printf("PARENT: array pocet hracu %d\n",players_array[index].mist->pocet_hracu);
                        printf("PARENT: lobby pocet hracu %d\n",lobby[0].pocet_hracu);
                        str str;
                        memset(sbuff, '\0', size);

                        //pokud v mistnosti jsou 2 hraci => zacina hra
                        if( players_array[index].mist->pocet_hracu == 2){
                            printf("Hra zacina ...\n");
                            hra(players_array[index].mist);
                        }
                        printMistnost(players_array[index].mist);
                    }

            //players_array[index].mist = lobby[volba - 1];
//        }

    }
    close(newSocket);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is my receive() function:

```
int receive(int socket, char *buff){
    int size = 256;
    int reader = recv(socket, buff, size * sizeof(char), 0);
    if (reader == -1) {
        printf("BREAK reader == -1\n");
        perror("recv()");
        return(-1);
    } else if (reader == 0) {
        printf("BREAK reader == 0\n");
        return(-2);
    } else if(checkMessage(buff) == 0){
        printf("ERROR: recieved message is not valid\n");
        return(-3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if I'm not using waitForAnswer variable the program connects without any errors with the client, but at some points stops at the beginning of while waiting for another message.

Comment: You need to redesign your app.

Comment: OT: The `receive()` function is broken "the usual" way. It is essential to understand, that `recv()` not necessarily receives as many bytes as it is told to, nor as many bytes as have been sent. You need to define a protocol and implement it. With the latter requiring to loop around `recv()` until all bytes expected have been received.

Comment: When dealing with blocking sockets, then `select()` is your friend.

Comment: `(e)poll()` is generally better to use than `select()`

Comment: One approach would be use a thread that handles the `recv()` while the main() handles the ongoing operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use ioctl() to check for data if the socket is set to non blocking

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>


int status;

do{
    ioctl(socketfd, FIONREAD, &status);
    if( status > 0 ){
     //packet waiting to be read
     recv(socketfd, buff, size * sizeof(char), 0);
    }
    else{
      // no data .. so do something else
    }
  } while (!must_stop);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call recv with the nonblocking flag:

```
recv(socket, buff, size, MSG_DONTWAIT);
```

And the function will immediately return if there was no data to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Now if I'm using nonblocking flag in while loop it's finising again with "No socket" error. I don't get why, cause the program didn't even get into while loop yet.

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you mean, can you be more precise? @iri